# How to use Tesseract to get text area from a certification card of the vehicle

Tags: python-2.7, ocr, python-tesseract

I need advice about tesseract. I have try to use Tesseract but the result is not perfect. A lot of information is missing.  I would like to scan a registration certificate for the french vehicle and I must to recuperate the data into database. You can find below the document, it's a french registration certificate. Is it possible to detect each area in this document and keep this information in database ? I have read on the internet and it's not possible to detect area with only Tesseract  ?

You have for example the area A, B, C.1,D.2.1. How to detect/scan each area and insert this information in the database ?

Example:
https://www.ecartegrise.fr/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/nouvelle-carte-grise-specimen.jpg

I would like to do this:
http://www.adoc-solutions.eu/images/Documentations/cartes-grises.png

How to recuperate each area text and insert this into a database ?

Thanks for your help

Nikolas

Answer (score 0):

I am actually working on a project similar to yours here are my suggestions 
 OCR techniques ? Optical Character recognition
There are a few OCR tools able to extract data from a pdf form or an image thanks to the OCR here are a list of OCR tools that i recommande :
-Convertio
-PDFMiner : PDF2txt-PDF2Word
-Tabula :  extracting data from a table 
-Abby FineReader 14
-DataWatch

if you have any complementary information please do share

Answer (score 0):

I am working on extracting tables and form data from PDF for quite some time. I think the solution to your problem is to first detect all those areas where the text is written and then create a mapping to columns.

If the registration form is static in nature means if the area of the text of particular fields is fixed then you can create a template specific to your problem and then crop the image from those defined coordinates and then try to apply tesseract.

Tesseract is not 100% correct so to improve accuracy you can train it on your data.